# C/C++ compressing library with encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, compression

I am developing some application for Win 7 OS performing biometric encryption. I want to use some free or proprietary library for data compression allowing to use custom encryption algorithms or with non-trivial set of embedded encryption algorithms. I will likely use AES, but I want to have ability to change particular algorithm easily or to allow user choose algorithm he want to use.

Another good feature could be fast single file extracting without decompressing entire archive, which could be very huge. Could you recommend me some tools?

Comment: @owlstead i'm just a student and interesting about compressing libraries allowing to use encryption, I find you comment rude and offensive

Comment: OK, apologies for the comment. Please do not use your code for live scenarios without expert review though. Biometric data is very sensitive. As a general hint; most biometrics can be compressed using specific compression techniques: JPG or JPG2000 for images, Wavelets or templates for fingerprints etc. Those kind of techniques are normally much better than standard compression techniques; and performing compression afterwards normally does not give you high compression rates.

Comment: @owlstead As biometric information I'm using ANSI/ISO specificated templates produced by biometric device support library. I'm not using my own or other uncertain algorithms. Such biometric just allows to use encryption secret key.

Comment: The biometric data in that case is probably pretty condensed, but you may be able to shave quite a bit off of the header information, which in contrast is not very compressed at all. As the biometric data itself is the bulk of the data, do not expect wonders.

Comment: @owlstead I don't want to compress biometric data. I want to compress some other data and encrypt it using some sort of key linked with user biometric information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [7zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), comes with a few compression algorithms and AES encryption.

> [...] with non-trivial set of embedded encryption algorithms

AES is enough for government, military, banking etc., so will be enough for you (subject to correct usage).